# count results in search page based on custom category

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have a seach page in which am showing results based on keyword and custom category search. Issue i am facing is that, I need to display the count of results. I had referred the wordpress documentation and found some codes, for eg :

```
<h2 class="pagetitle">Search Result for <?php 
    /* Search Count */ 
    $allsearch = &new WP_Query("s=$s&showposts=-1"); 
    $key = wp_specialchars($s, 1); 
    $count = $allsearch->post_count; 
    _e(''); 
    _e('<span class="search-terms">'); 
    echo $key; 
    _e('</span>'); 
    _e(' &mdash; '); 
    echo $count . ' '; 
    _e('articles'); 
    wp_reset_query(); 
?></h2>
```

But this displays the total search results and I need results count filtered by found in the specified category

Comment: pay attention that `showposts` arguments is deprecated as of version 2.1, use `posts_per_page` instead

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wp_count_posts ?
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_count_posts

I think that will work here.